# Django API returning a single object rather than my whole list when using Table.objects.filter(condition)

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

In my Django project I have two tables: User and Post, where each Post has a foreign key 'author' to a User. I want to display all the posts that belong to a single user, with the URL:
`.../users/<int:pk>/posts.`

I parse this into my view function with the header: `def user_post_list(request, pk):`, which to my knowledge gives my view function access to this int:pk variable.
I define the posts I want to return using `posts = Post.objects.filter(author=pk)`, which should give me a list of all the objects that have an 'author' attribute equal to int:pk. However, when I go to return these posts, rather than a list I get only one JSON object from the Post table with an 'id' attribute and 'author' attribute equal to int:pk

(EDIT) **views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_post_list(request, pk):
    try:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=pk)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True) #converts Python to JSON for post with ID
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe = False) #returns
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
   content = models.TextField()
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py:

```
path('users/<int:pk>/posts/', views.post_detail)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you put the code of your views so that we can investigate ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Charlesthk I've put the code for my views in now

Comment: I have edited my answer, your url must point to `user_post_list` not `post_detail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url point to `post_detail` and not `user_post_list`, change your `urls.py` like this :

```py
path('users/<int:pk>/posts/', views.user_post_list)
```

You need to use `Response` from Django Rest Framework :

If `author` if a `ForeignKey` make sure to use `author_id` in your filter condition.

You don't need to catch `Post.DoesNotExist` since it is only applicable to `get()` method of queryset.

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response

@csrf_exempt
def user_post_list(request, pk):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author_id=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True) 
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Ok sure, is this still in JSON format? Also, if I were to change '.filter()' to '.all()', it does in fact return a list using JsonResponse(), why is this?

Comment: This actually didn't change anything, it still just returns a single object. I think it is returning Posts with and id of x rather than author x

Comment: Does you PostSerializer inherits from ModelSerializer ?

Comment: You can also make sur to use `author_id` instead of `author` in your filter condition

Comment: It does inherit from ModelSerializer

Comment: I changed author to author_id and it made no difference

Comment: I deleted the post with id=4, and now I get no results for Post.objects.filter(author_id=pk) when <int:pk> is set to for in the URL. It must be filtering by the Post table primary key, rather than the Post tables foreign key, 'author'. Why is this?

Comment: I've added my models and urls for context